# Cucumber plants wilting and dying outside during a rainy summer

Tags: vegetables, watering, container-gardening, drainage

I have several cucumber plants planted outside (I'm in Zone 4). They are planted in large containers or raised garden beds.

hey were doing okay until about a week ago when we started having rain every day. The plants are wilting and dying and I don't know what to do. They are obviously well-watered because of the rain, at night the temperature is around 10C.

Is this something that can be caused by rain? We also had some small hail but it didn't damage the leaves, although I am curious if it chilled the plants too much. The soil is wet, but not soggy/swampy.

Is there anything I can do to help the ones that are struggling but still alive? My watermelon plant is dying too now (leaves curling and wilting) and I'm getting a bit more desperate as I see more and more plants being affected.

Comment: maybe some kind of root rot?

Comment: Can you post a photo?  Cooling from hail is not the culprit.  I'm wondering about powdery mildew.  Also, what is the drainage like for letting excess water out the bottom of the raised beds?

Comment: @InColorado, I don't think its powdery mildew, I'm quite familiar with that, unfortunately, but it typically occurs in my greenhouse. This wilting was so sudden, literally overnight. The raised beds are about 2ft deep built on top of our lawn, the water drains into the soil below. Unfortunately the dead plants wilted and essentially fell apart and so I can't really get any pictures anymore. The zucchini plants that were in the same beds are doing great, so at least that's good I guess :)

Comment: I'm stumped.  I'll be interested what ideas others may come up with.